# Cannot call method 'jsonp' of undefined in Angular.js controller

Tags: angularjs

The following controller is producing the error message "Cannot call method 'jsonp' of undefined".  I suspect that I am not injecting $http properly.  Can someone tell me what I've done incorrectly?

```
'use strict';

/* Controllers */

angular.module('myApp.controllers', []).

  controller('ImagesCtrl', [function ImagesCtrl ($scope, $http) {
    $http.jsonp('http://localhost:3000/image?quantity=1&language=Cantonese&callback=JSON_CALLBACK')
    .success(function(data){
      console.log(data);
      $scope.image = data;
    }); 

  }])


  .controller('CaptionsCtrl', [function() {

  }]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are not injecting dependencies properly

```
app.controller(<controller_name>, ['$scope', function($scope) {}]);
```

in your case that should be

```
app.controller('ImagesCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {}]);
```

Or if you prefer not to use annotations (which are good for minification):

```
app.controller('ImagesCtrl', function () {
    console.log("in the controller");
});
```