# Injecting $http and $scope into function within controller

Tags: angularjs

I asked a similar question earlier when attempting to inject $scope and $http into a controller [Cannot call method 'jsonp' of undefined in Angular.js controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17471721/cannot-call-method-jsonp-of-undefined-in-angular-js-controller).  Now I'm attempting to refactor that code slightly by moving the code into a function within the controller.  I'm encountering similar issues and can't seem to grasp the mechanics of dependency injection in Angular.  Below is my new code.  Both $scope and $http are undefined.  What I'm attempting to do is make an http request when didSelectLanguage() fires and assign the resulting data to the "image" variable in the $scope from the parent controller.  Can someone enlighten me as to how dependency injection is supposed to work in this example?

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers', []).

  controller('ImagesCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {



        $scope.didSelectLanguage=function($scope, $http) {
            console.log($scope);
            $http.jsonp('http://localhost:3000/image?quantity=1&language='+this.language+'&Flag=&callback=JSON_CALLBACK')
            .success(function(data){
            $scope.image = data;
            });

        }

  }])
```

Comment: This isn't the immediate answer to your question, but the article I wrote at [What “things” can be injected into others in Angular.js?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16828287/what-things-can-be-injected-into-others-in-angular-js/16829270#16829270) (also "Understanding Dependency Injection" on the AngularJS wiki), specifically the part on `$injector`, explains how DI works at a lower level, and may help you understand why certain code works or doesn't work.

Comment: That's an outstanding article! +1 on both.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

When you create your controller:

```javascript
angular.module('myApp.controllers', []).
controller('ImagesCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
  // ...
}]);
```

The stuff inside the body of the controller function automatically has access to `$scope` and `$http` because of [closures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work). Thus, there's no need to specify anything additional for a function on the `$scope` to have access to these things:

```javascript
angular.module('myApp.controllers', []).
controller('ImagesCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {

  $scope.didSelectLanguage = function() {
    $http.jsonp('http://localhost:3000/image?quantity=1&language=' + this.language + '&Flag=&callback=JSON_CALLBACK');
      .success(function(data) {
        $scope.$parent.image = data;
      });
  }

}]);
```

When `didSelectLanguage` is run, it sees the references to `$http`, and reaches *out* of the function into the *outer* function to get the value of the reference; the same happens for `$scope` inside the success callback.

So, in short, there's no need to pass any arguments to your `didSelectLanguage` function, nor is there in this case any reason to use the `$injector`.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of Michelle Tilley's comment & article I solved the problem as follows.  However, I'm going to keep the question open until someone else answers or until I understand enough to write an accompanying explanation.

```
controller('ImagesCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$injector', function ($scope, $http, $injector) {

    $scope.didSelectLanguage=function() {

            $http.jsonp('http://localhost:3000/image?quantity=1&language='+this.language+'&Flag=&callback=JSON_CALLBACK')
            .success(function(data){
            $scope.$parent.image = data;
            });

        }

  }])
```